# PHP, Ajax, JSON, and Handlebars

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, handlebars.js

If this is a redundant question please let me know and point me there, but I am not finding the exact question/answer combination nor a mixture of the two.

I have some ajax in jquery that calls a function from a php page. Without the handlebars the json data comes back nice and pretty.  No issues there.  However I can't seem to get ajax to write out my results to a handlebars template.  Here is the code I have now:

```
$.ajax({
type: "post",
    url: "../includes/db_functions.inc.php",
    data: ({ p : p, p2 : p2, f : f }),
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(results){
$.each(results, function(i, item){
     var context = [ 
     {
            id : item[i].id, 
            clock_number : item[i].clock_number,
     }
    ],
    template = Handlebars.compile( $('#template').html() );
    $('table.entries').append( template(context) );
});
}
});
```

anyone know what I might be missing here?  I 99% sure its in the context area, but just not finding it.

[edit]

```
<table class="entries">
    <script id="template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
            <tr>
                <td>{{id}}</td>
                <td>{{clock_number}}</td>
            </tr>
    </script>
</table>
```

Comment: Am I the only monkey that has tried to do this? lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Handlebars - Getting Started](http://handlebarsjs.com/), I would say, leave out the array and use just the object as context

```
var context = {
    id : item[i].id, 
    clock_number : item[i].clock_number,
},
template = Handlebars.compile($('#template').html());
$('table.entries').append(template(context));
```

In the ajax `success` code, there's the call to `$.each(results, function(i, item) {...})`. In this context, `item` is already the `i`th element, if `results` is an array. Maybe you can reduce this to

```
success: function(results) {
    var template = Handlebars.compile($('#template').html());
    $.each(results, function(i, context) {
        $('table.entries').append(template(context));
    });
}
```

Comment: I had tried that before, going through the handlebars page that you posted, but no joy.  I did try it again, but again with no joy. It's funny without handlebars I can display the data with no problem. I just wanted to use a more template based solution.

Comment: @tattooedgeek Then there must be a problem with the template itself. Can you show it in your question?

Comment: @tattooedgeek I just tested the template with the `context` as array (doesn't work) and with `context` as an object (works). Unfortunately, jsfiddle.net says forbidden when I try to save it, so I can't show it right now.

Comment: Thanks Olaf, interesting. I'll keep tinkering with it then. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so there were actually several things wrong here.

First I had a typo in the form itself, although it did not fix the issue would have caused me not to find the fix.

Second, couldn't use the $('#submit').on("click", function())  for some reason it just didn't like it.  I changed it to a $('#textbox).on("blur", function()) and immediately started getting results from the success function.

Third, yeah ok I don't know if this was actually an issue, but it works so I'm calling it part of the answer. Do what @Olaf Dietsche with the $.each, something like this:

```
$.each(results, function(i, context){
   $('div.entry').append( template(context) );
});
```